# Multiple WordPress Installations with Nginx

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I am trying to use a single site config file with nginx to server an arbitrary number of WordPress installations in sub-folders, but can't get pretty permalinks to work at all.

```
+ root
    + WordPressOne
    + WordPressTwo
    + WordPressThree
```

With permalinks disabled, `/WordPressOne/?p=12` works fine. With permalinks enabled, `/WordPressOne/MyPage/` results in a 404 delivered from the root folder.

Since the number of WP installations in subfolders is constantly varying (it's used for development) and I don't want to have to constantly modify/create/delete site configs, I'd like it to work such that I can just copy a new WordPress installation to a new subfolder, set WP up, and have permalinks working for that installation without restarting nginx or PHP-FPM.

This is the basic `site.conf` used in the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` folder (it reflects a number of rules used in production as well):

```
server {
    listen 5000 default;
    server_name dev wpdev;
    root /vagrant/sites;
    client_max_body_size 2m;
    expires -1;
    charset utf-8;
    index index.html index.php;

    location ~* ^.+\.(manifest|appcache)$ {
        expires -1;
        index index.html index.htm;
        uwsgi_cache off;
    }

    location ~* \.(?:rss|atom)$ {
        expires 1h;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(css    |js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|gz|svg|svgz|ttf|otf|woff|eot|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|txt)$ {
        expires max;
        access_log off;
        index index.html index.htm;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        uwsgi_cache off;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        uwsgi_cache off;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        uwsgi_cache off;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    add_header "X-UA-Compatible" "IE=Edge,chrome=1";
    add_header "Vary" "Accept-Language";
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*";
    add_header "Cache-Control" "no-transform";
}
```

This is also used as part of a virtual machine configuration (using Vagrant, as you can see), and I'd love for designers and WP devs to not have to worry about keeping their site files in nginx updated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've copied a basic WordPress setup and I see no attempts to implement the logic you want. Each WordPress install has a router called index.php, which should be the catch-all for pretty URLs to work. They will need to carry the first path below the site root, which is probably a WordPress configuration setting.
Then you will need to set the root based on the first path component in the request_uri and route non existing files and directories to the appropriate index.php.
I'm not entirely sure this would work and can't test it for time constraints, so try this and report back:

```
set $wpinstall = '';
location ~ /([^/]+)/(.*)$ {
    set $wpinstall = $1;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @wp;
}

location @wp {
    rewrite /$wpinstall/ /$wpinstall/index.php;
}

location ~ ^(.+\.php)(.*)$ {
    root /vagrant/sites;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.*\.php)(.*)$;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$wpinstall$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    #...rest of fastcgi parameters
}
```

If you report back, be sure to include the rewriting debug info by setting the appropriate `error_log` debug level. In all honesty, this may be a lot easier if you use virtual hosts, based on [this configuration](http://publications.jbfavre.org/web/nginx-vhosts-automatiques-avec-SSL-et-authentification-version2.en). Your developers would only need to edit their host files.

Comment: This kind of worked, actually, but all the assets (stylesheets, images, etc.) ended up being rewritten as well.

Comment: I've made a "business decision" and decided we'll just do these developer VMs with Apache instead and let the htaccess files deal with the rewriting. But thanks anyways!